# NoClassDefFoundError after exporting jar

Tags: java, mongodb, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to work with MongoDB in my Java projects.
After exporting my project to a file I get a no class defined error for the MongoClient.
I get no errors while exporting.
I use Maven to import the different dependencies and all jars are being exported properly

```java
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;

public class MongoDB {

    private static MongoClient client;

    public static void init() {
        try {
            client = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017/xenoncraft");
            System.out.println("[XenonSuite] Successfully connected to MongoDB");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[XenonSuite] Following errors were catched while connecting to MongoDB");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not an expert in Maven, but maybe you'd best look to be sure that you're using it correctly since it looks like you may be missing a dependency.

Comment: Also, does your jar file have a decent manifest file?

Comment: No I think I do not need one because I'm executing it as a plugin

Comment: can you add more context, are you running it as `java -jar jar_name.jar` or some other way?, are you using any java framework along with mongodb?

Comment: I am running it as a plugin on a minecraft server. The start of the server shouldnt be affecting the plugin

Comment: How do you test whether your plugin is working fine or not, will `java -jar jar_name.jar` will be sufficient?

Comment: Can you provide the error details ?

Comment: @dkb I have the server file which executes the plugin I am exporting.

Comment: @Sambit java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/client/MongoClients
        at de.xenonsuite.helpers.MongoDB.init(MongoDB.java:13) ~[?:?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved your issue:
Checkout project from [Github source code:](https://github.com/dineshbhagat/platform/blob/master/test.zip)
unzip, build, test
OR
1. Created a maven project
`mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4`

2. Update pom.xml with following, added mongo client code from OP and printing collection names
3. Execute 
   `mvn clean package`
4. Execute
   `java -jar test.jar`
   output I got is:

```
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:9}] to localhost:27017
Jun 01, 2019 8:17:22 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 0, 5]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=2249770}
Jun 01, 2019 8:17:22 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:10}] to localhost:27017
admin
config
local
test
[XenonSuite] Successfully connected to MongoDB
```

**pom.xml**(ignore package names)
Check **shade plugin configuration**

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>test</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <mainClass>test.App</mainClass>
  </properties>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.1</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <transformers>
                  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                    <mainClass>test.App</mainClass>
                  </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <finalName>test</finalName>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

There are multiple ways to solve this problem
Ref: https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that, you have the following dependency in Maven pom.xml.

org.mongodb
    mongodb-driver
    3.9.1

If you are not using maven, you have to download this jar file from mvnrepository.com and also you have to download bson.jar, mongodb-driver-core with the version 3.9.1 and you have to download slf4j-api.jar with version 1.7.6.

Comment: I am using the mongodb-driver version 3.10.1. I added the dependecy in my pom.xml and have it listed under my Maven dependencies. Whats the slf4j-api.jar?

Comment: slf4j-api is used for logging. Mongodb driver client has dependency with this jar file also. If you look into the dependency of mongodb driver in mvnrepository.com, you can see and able to understand.